# Creating a multiple directories based on csv dictionary - python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, directory

I am trying to create new folders based on the values in my dictionary. I have read in a csv file that is my dictionary where the key is the ad name and value is the company. I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the code to make a new file based on the company name and then move the appropriate ad file into the corresponding company name file. I'm very new to python, any help would be appreciated!

Csv file:

```
C:\\Test Ad Names\\newFiles\\MAN OPENING YOGURT.SNACK TO WIN.CC..mp4, GROUPE DANONE
C:\\Test Ad Names\\newFiles\\ECONOMAX. OIKOS. KOMBU.NOOVO.BB_2.mp4, GROUPE DANONE
```

Current attempt at code:

```
import csv
import os
import shutil

# make an empty dictionary which will hold the keys
keys = {}

#open file
with open('C:/TestingGroupingAds.csv','r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
# build a dictionary with the associated ids
        for rowDict in reader:
              keys[ rowDict[0] ] = rowDict[1]
              print(rowDict)

# need to group files based on dictionary
source = os.listdir('C:\Test Ad Names\newFiles')
destinationpath = 'C:\Test Ad Names\newFiles\groupedByCompany'

# if the value (company name) does not exist then make a new file
for key, value in keys.items():
    if not os.path.exists(value):
        os.makedirs(value)
    for file in source:
        shutil.move(value, key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're pretty close but there are a few things that look like need to be changed:

1. The code isn't using `destinationpath` anywhere.
2. The usage of os.listdir seems uncesssary if the csv file already has all of the files mapped with a path - just use that as the path.

Here's an example:

```
# need to group files based on dictionary
source = os.listdir('C:\Test Ad Names\newFiles')
destination_path = 'C:\Test Ad Names\newFiles\groupedByCompany\\'

# if the value (company name) does not exist then make a new file
for key, value in keys.items():
    new_directory = destination_path + value
    if not os.path.exists(new_directory):
        os.makedirs(new_directory)
    for file in source:
        shutil.move(value, new_directory)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up switching to shutil.copy to achieve this task, but it's taking quite a while to run this process...is there any faster way to copy these files or speed this process up?

Comment: If you don't need it to continue living in the directory, using `shutil.move` would be faster otherwise you're limited because copying forces the file to essentially be recreated in a new place.